# Will Hainan Airlines provide me with a new shrink-wrapped blanket or should I take my own?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, china, manchester

I’m soon to be travelling via Hainan Airlines from Manchester to Beijing and wonder whether packing my own blanket would be worth it if I can get a new one on the plane. Would save me loads of packaging space in my hand luggage if so.

Comment: is it a night flight? are you in economy?

Answer (score 5):

I checked [the web site for Hainan](https://www.hainanairlines.com/HUPortal/dyn/portal/DisplayPage?COUNTRY_SITE=CA&SITE=CBHZCBHZ&LANGUAGE=GB&PAGE=ECNO) and they say:

> To make your flight even more comfortable and convenient, we have carefully selected a series of items for you to use, including soft and comfortable blankets and fluffy waist pillows, allowing you to relax your entire body and enjoy a splendid journey.

There is no mention of whether the blankets are shrink-wrapped. If this is important to you, or if the blankets not being loaded would ruin the flight for you, consider bringing your own. But not a huge bed blanket from home. You can buy special travel blankets that fold up small. I use a pashmina, because silk folds really small and it's warm, plus I can use it for other purposes during my trip.

Comment: That was a really lovely reply, thank you. I don’t intend on bringing my bed blanket because that’d be way too big. I have to sell all my things because I’m actually emigrating to China from the UK so buying new things is going to have to be considered. Think I will look into getting a pashmina, though- thanks!

Comment: I think the blanket is in a loose plastic bag. That's my vague recollection from the last couple times I've flow on Hainan YYZ<->PEK. Of course if you're leaving from Manchester it might be different.

Answer (score 0):

Bring your own! Blankets and pillows are not always washed between uses, even if they're in plastic. There are many travel blankets, or small polar fleece blankets, to use instead. Depending on the season, could you just use your coat?

A cheap option I've done is to buy a meter or so of polar fleece from a fabric store, roll it into a tiny bag, and use that. It is also very easy to wash after the flight.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have proof; I'm speaking from personal experience. I've flown with my own tiny blanket for years, airplanes are incredibly dirty, and he can save a few $/£/€ this way.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm glad you've had good experiences. It might be a myth, but I would not underestimate the willingness of airlines in the US to save money by not washing them. Regardless, it costs something like $8 per flight on a domestic flight here, so bringing my own blanket cuts down on costs, especially when I fly several times per year.